# Multithreading in Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Не могу понять какая разница между первой и второй реализацией, кто сможет объяснить?

```
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    NewThread newThread =  new NewThread(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

    for(int i = 0;i < 5; i++){

        executorService.execute(newThread);
    }



    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    for(int i = 0;i < 5; i++){
        NewThread newThread =  new NewThread(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        executorService.execute(newThread);
    }
```

Comment: Ну это как бы очевидно, что в первом случае используется один и тот же newThread, во втором каждый раз создаётся новый newThread.

Comment: Ну как бы это я понял, в результате там и там беде по 5 одинаковых потоков?

Comment: В каком-то смысле одинаковых. Что именно понимается под одинаковостью?

Comment: @Dima Kovbasa, укажите реализацию NewThread в вопросе.

Comment: В первом случае newThread может использоваться в пределах всего класса. Во втором случае только внутри цикла, и он недоступен за пределами for.